# Python - How to improve performance of subsetting tuple key dictionaries through for loop?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop

I have two dictionaries with tuple keys. I subsetted each dictionary into 3 small dictionaries and then applied the prediction model to each dictionary. See below,

```
# Subset dictionaries from df_dict140 and df_dict150
# df_dict140 has 456 rows and df_dict150 has 415
# I subsetted the them by 200
dic1 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict140[:200]}
dic2 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict140[200:400]}
dic3 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict140[400:456]}

dic4 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict150[:200]}
dic5 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict150[200:400]}
dic6 = {k: df_dic[k] for k in df_dict150[400:415]}
```

Applied the model to each dictionary,

```
def predictionModel(pred_dict): 
    prediction = {}
    for (key1, key2), value in pred_dict.items():
        m = Prophet().fit(value)
        future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 365)
        forecast = m.predict(future)
        prediction[key2] = forecast[['ds','yhat']].tail()    
    return prediction
```

Prediction results,

```
prediction1 = predictionModel(dic1)
prediction2 = predictionModel(dic2)
prediction3 = predictionModel(dic3)
prediction4 = predictionModel(dic4)
prediction5 = predictionModel(dic5)
prediction6 = predictionModel(dic6)
```

Is it possible to write a function or for loop to do the above work so that no need to subset the dictionaries twice and can get the results by once.

Comment: `forecast[['ds','yhat']]`: is that a dictionary? in which case it's not correct. lists are not hashable.

Comment: What do you mean by definition? It is not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's a data frame.

Comment: `predictionModel` looks to be  linear time on the number of dictionary items.  I don't understand what problem is being solved by splitting  them up.

Comment: @AShelly Because when I ran the model with all the items in the dictionary(which are 456 & 416), it took a long time to run, so I split them up by 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Note that Python will let you index beyond the end of lists without issue
smaller_dicts = [{k: df_dic[k] for k in dfd[200*i:200*(i+1)]}
                 for dfd in [df_dict140, df_dict150]
                 for i in range(3)]

predictions = [predictionModel(sd) for sd in smaller_dicts]
```

Comment: May I know if we can do that for two dictionaries at a time? First line`{k: df_dic[k] for k in dfd[200*i : 200*(i+1)]}` is working for one dictionary(dfd).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you are doing with Prophet, but if you just want to slice the dictionaries programmatically:

```
for i in range(0,max(len(dict140),len(dict150)),200):
    d140_slice = {k: df_dic[k] for k in dict140[i:i+200]}
    d150_slice = {k: df_dic[k] for k in dict150[i:i+200]}
    #do something with the slices.
```

Comment: Prophet is a forecasting package created by Facebook. I am using it do daily prediction. I ran into TypeError: unhashable : 'slice'

Comment: I fixed the TypeError problem, but the code above generated only two subsets(one for each subset). I would like to generate subsets conditionally. For example, I want to split by 200 rows, so dictionary with 456 rows will have 3 subsets(200, 200, 56 each) with the last subset containing 46 rows.